# How to detect when a UIPageViewController's view has changed

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app with a PageViewController and I want to make my own custom PageViewController indicator. Everything is all set up. The only thing I need to do now is to figure out how to tell when the view controller's view has changed and what view it is currently on.

I have linked to [this demo](https://vimeo.com/258716090). In the first part I am clicking on the buttons at the top to change the page and the slider indicating what the current page is working, however after that I swipe my finger to change the controller, and I want to make the slider indicator to move with the page.

Answer (score 2):

Here I had commented what to do for getting current Page index using PageViewController

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
    {
        if (completed)
        {
            //No need as we had Already managed This action in other Delegate
        }
        else
        {
            ///Update Current Index
            Manager.pageindex = Manager.lastIndex

            ///Post notification to hide the draggable Menu
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateLabelValue"), object: nil)
        }
    }

    //MARK: Check Transition State
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])
    {
        ///Update Last Index
        Manager.lastIndex = Manager.pageindex

        ///Update Index
        Manager.pageindex = pages.index(of: pendingViewControllers[0])!

        ///Post notification to hide the draggable Menu
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateLabelValue"), object: nil)
    }
```

I Had used **Notification Observer** to Notify the main controller about page Change and Performing some action

**Manager** is my struct , that hold the current page number , you can make hold the index in struct or in class wherever you want

**My struct class**

```
//Struct Class
struct Manager
{
    ///Current Page Index
    static var pageindex :Int = 0

    ///Last Index
    static var lastIndex :Int = 0
}
```

**Main usage**

```
switch Manager.pageindex
        {
        case 0:
            self.mainHomeLabel.text = "VC1"
        case 1:
            self.mainHomeLabel.text = "VC2"
        case 2:
            self.mainHomeLabel.text = "VC3"
        default:
            self.mainHomeLabel.text = "VC1"
        }
```

**Note** Any queries in the respective code Please ask

**Update - Added Demo Project Link**

Link - https://github.com/RockinGarg/PageViewController-Demo.git

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer its much appreciated. I think I understand what your getting to bud can you please help me a little bit with the implementation, in which classes do I put this code?

Comment: Okay I will share sample project with you

Comment: I had shared a demo project created , Kindly check that will give you All Steps required

Comment: Thank you very much, I did everything you said and it is very straight forward however my _______ func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) _____ is never even getting called and I do have the delegate

Comment: let me check please

Comment: it Is not called only in case of Delegate is not provided , can you share code or preferably Xcode project if possible with me ? and did you checked my flow in Sample code is it same as yours >

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of the pages you're showing then you could use the UIPageViewControllerDelegate to detect page changes. More specifically this function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate/1614091-pageviewcontroller as it will tell you what you are about to transition to. You could then determine what page you are on based on the view controller that is about to be presented.